# Simulated Annealing Algorithm to solve Bin Packing

Tags: algorithm

I'm researching about `Bin Packing` Problem. I currently have implemented this problem in Genetic Programming way. But when I research Simulated Annealing Algorithm for this problem, I don't understand it very well.

Is there any good link or code / psuedocode for this problem.

Comment: Before rain of down votes, and close proposals, I suggest to ask/move this on/to the Computer Science SE. IMO, your problem in current form is far too little technical for a proper SO question. You are asking for a broad research materials, that are "good" which makes answers biased and opinion based. Personally, I simply feel you will have much greater reception and chances asking there.

Comment: Also, I think it's probably slightly more likely that the "problem" you are looking into is "bin packing", not "bin packet"...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First let us define the problem

Pack a set of 
`N = {1, 2, …, n}` items, each with size 
`t_i, i =1, 2,…, n,` into identical bins, each with capacity `C`

Minimize the number of bins without violating the capacity constraints

So main Outline of Annealing Algorithm will consist on:

- Construct an initial solution using first-fit decreasing procedure
- Compute and assign weights to items to distort sizes according 
  to the packing solutions of individual bins
- Perform local search by swapping items betweenall pairs of bins
- Carry out re-weighting based on the result of the previous 
  optimization run
- Reduce weight distortion according to a cooling schedule

Now it is important to do a Neighborhood Search for Bin Packing Problem:

- From a current solution, obtain the next solution by swapping items between bins 
  with the following objective function (Fleszar and Hindi 2002)

[image]

- Swap schemes
  Swap items between two bins, then Carry out Swap (1,0), Swap (1,1), Swap (1,2), Swap 
  (2,2) for all pairs of bins.
- Swap (1,0)

[image]
 - then evaluate only the change in the objective function value

- Swap (1,1), then Swap (1,2) like:
  [image]

That should give you a start.

Comment: I have read some link, that said about `temperature` `scaling` parameter, and they define a formula to count weight of bin i such as : `wi = 1 + K * ri`, But in algorithm, I don't understand this formula role. can you explain for me ? thanks :)

Comment: and can you explain for me about swap(0,1) swap(1,2) ... clearer, please ? does it means swap 0th element at bin a with 1th element at bin b ? or anything else ? thanks :)